# JS Image Manipulation - Auto crop out extra background around object

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

I'm making an application where users will upload photos (most of them should be some kind of logos) and later converting that photo to an svg.
[image: Sample image]
In the image above i want to cut the image where the red rectangle is before converting to svg.

I tried this with MarvinJ (https://www.marvinj.org/en/index.html) as in the example (Detect Features) but could not get consistent results.

Later i tried this with trackingjs (https://trackingjs.com/), but also without consistent results.
[image: trackingjs]
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the red rectangle coordinate/dimension information?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, in your case, you should simply find non-background pixels fitting in a rectangle. This version will only work for light backgrounds. You'll need to change it to make it work in other scenarios.

**result for two logos:**

[image]

[image]

**runnable code below:**

```js
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var image1 = new MarvinImage();
var image2 = new MarvinImage();
image1.load("https://i.imgur.com/0maopmf.jpg", image1Loaded);
image2.load("https://i.imgur.com/rWcofCi.jpg", image2Loaded);

function image1Loaded(){
  processImage(image1, canvas1);
}
function image2Loaded(){
  processImage(image2, canvas2);
}
function processImage(image, canvas){
  var bbox = boundingBox(image);
  image.drawRect(bbox[0]-10, bbox[1]-10, bbox[2]-bbox[0]+20, bbox[3]-bbox[1]+20, 0xFFFF0000);
  image.draw(canvas);
}

function boundingBox(image){
  var x1=9999, x2=-1, y1=9999, y2=-1;
  var img = image.clone();
  Marvin.thresholding(img, img, 127);
  for(var y=0; y<img.getHeight(); y++){
    for(var x=0; x<img.getWidth(); x++){
      // Is Black (Object)?
      if(img.getIntColor(x,y) == 0xFF000000){
        if(x < x1) x1 = x;
        if(x > x2) x2 = x;
        if(y < y1) y1 = y;
        if(y > y2) y2 = y;
  }}}
  return [x1, y1, x2, y2];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.marvinj.org/releases/marvinj-0.9.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="600" height="347"></canvas>
```